# Why does TSQL on Sql Server 2000 round decimals inconsistently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, rounding

I'm trying to calculate percent off values for dollar amounts. At 50%, sometimes you get half a penny, and I need to round it to the nearest cent.

In Sql, my calculation is as follows:

`round(retail * 0.5, 2, 0)`

If I take the following values I get different results:

- 4.39
- 2.49

Unrounded I get:

- 4.39 --> 2.195
- 2.49 --> 1.245

When rounded I get:

- 2.195 --> 2.19
- 1.245 --> 1.25

I'm told this is a form of "banker's rounding", but it seems like the value that is affecting the rounding direction is the integer value.

My problem is that I expect the top value to round to 2.20. If this is indeed bankers rounding, and it is affected by the integer value here, does anyone have an example for preventing this behavior. If it is not bankers rounding, can someone please provide an explanation and potentially a solution to just get normal rounding behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, i tried this in sql server 2008 and I get 2.200; cannot help you with sql 2000 though have you tried this: select round(4.39*0.5,2,0) => my result =2.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the data type of `retail`?  I can't test this on SQL 2000, but on SQL 2008 R2, I see similar results if I use `float`.

```
float:         4.39 --> 2.195, rounds to 2.19 
               2.49 --> 1.245, rounds to 1.25

money:         4.39 --> 2.195, rounds to 2.20
               2.49 --> 1.245, rounds to 1.25

decimal(5,2):  4.39 --> 2.195, rounds to 2.20
               2.49 --> 1.245, rounds to 1.25
```

---

To show the approximation created by `float`, you can cast to `decimal(20,19)` and it becomes clear why it's rounding this way:

```
4.39 * 0.5 --> 2.1949999999999999000
2.49 * 0.5 --> 1.2450000000000001000
```

Comment: I was using float. I will test with the other types. I didn't even think to do that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  This is a good example of why you would use `money` or `decimal` instead of an approximate data type like `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some rounding methods here: [SQL Server Rounding Methods](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-rounding-methods) bankers rounding is explained

Comment: Caveat: the referenced article makes the same mistake as demonstrated by Jeff Ogata's answer -- datatype changes the behavior of the ROUND() function. A fairly thorough (non-language specific) analysis of rounding methods is explained in the Wikipedia article [Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).