# Sql server round interpreting 5 as lower

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, sql-query-store

I want to round decimals in sql server 2012 for example:

```
Select ROUND(1.056,2) -- returns  1.06
Select ROUND(1.055,2) -- returns  1.06
Select ROUND(1.054,2) -- returns  1.05
```

How can I make the second query returns 1.05 rounding the third decimal if 5 to lower?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding down decimal numbers in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072136/rounding-down-decimal-numbers-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847374/sql-server-rounding-issue-where-there-is-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. It will work for you.

```
DECLARE @test decimal(10,3) = 1.055
SELECT CASE WHEN round(@test,3,1) - round(@test,2,1) = 0.005 THEN round(@test,2,1) ELSE round(@test,2) END
```

Answer (score 1):

Select only 2 digits from the field. This will select high number in 4th position or 5th position

```
 select    
 case when  right ( 'colvalue',1) >  right (SUBSTRING('colValue',1,4),1) 
 then ROUND('colvalue',2)
 else ROUND (LEFT ( 'colvalue',4) ,2) end RoundValue
```

Comment: I still want SELECT round(1.056,2,1) to return 1.06

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as third argument of round(). If the function returns 0 then the result is rounded otherwise the result is truncated.

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )  

SELECT round(1.055,2,1)
```

Edit:

Here is a complete example...

```
create table test
(
    n decimal(10,7) not null
)
GO

insert into test (n)
values 
(1.050),
(1.051),
(1.052),
(1.053),
(1.054),
(1.055),
(1.056),
(1.057),
(1.058),
(1.059)
GO

select n, round(n,2,iif(n - round(n,2,1)>.005,0,1)) as rounded from test
GO
```

Here is the result :

```
n           rounded
1.0500000   1.0500000
1.0510000   1.0500000
1.0520000   1.0500000
1.0530000   1.0500000
1.0540000   1.0500000
1.0550000   1.0500000
1.0560000   1.0600000
1.0570000   1.0600000
1.0580000   1.0600000
1.0590000   1.0600000
```

Comment: I still want SELECT round(1.056,2,1) to return 1.06

Answer (score 0):

I would go with simple:

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @test_string nvarchar(10)

SET @test_string='1.055'
-- SET @test_string='1.056' -- is here to test
SET @test = SUBSTRING(@test_string,5,5)


IF @test=5
BEGIN
   SELECT ROUND (LEFT(@test_string,4),2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT ROUND (@test_string,2)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the rounded value:

```
Select CAST(ROUND(1.056,2) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) -- returns  1.06
Select CAST(ROUND(1.055,2) AS NUMERIC(10,2))  -- returns  1.06
Select CAST(ROUND(1.054,2) AS NUMERIC(10,2))  -- returns  1.05
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I solved it in a slightly different way. What does banker's rounding DO anyways? I just recreated it using nested ROUND() functions, because that's literally what we are doing when we round using Banker's Rounding. You just have to have to start rounding at your precision level, and then work your way backwards from there to 2 decimal places.

For example, if you have a 5 decimal precision number, you'd do this:

```
SELECT ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(54.14356, 5), 4), 3), 2) = 54.14000
```

It's not pretty, and I'm sure you could somehow encapsulate it into a function, but I only needed it in one place anyways, so I just hard-coded the cascade.

It's literally doing it how we'd do it in our head:

```
54.14356 => 54.1436 => 54.144
```

Makes sense to me! Now if you're dealing with an 18 point precision decimal... might be time to put that into a procedure, heh.